# My WPF ChromeWindow is slightly off when maximized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I built this sample application and using a custom WindowChrome with WPF and C#. Everytime I try to maximize my window using the buttons I made, the maximized window becomes slightly off? Like by a few pixels. What is happening?

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestApp"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        MinHeight="500" MinWidth="940">

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome 
            ResizeBorderThickness="6"
            CaptionHeight="20"
            GlassFrameThickness="0"
            CornerRadius="0"
            />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <!-- Application -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- WindowChrone Header -->
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource WindowChromeBrush}" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="RelayC" />
            <Button Click="MinimizeWindow" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource WindowChromeButton}">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource window_minimize_icon}"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="MaximizeWindow" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource WindowChromeButton}">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource window_maximize_icon}" />
            </Button>
            <Button Click="CloseWindow" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource WindowChromeButton}">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource window_close_icon}" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>

           <!--- Main Content -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my sample code for the Button Functions:

```
    private void MinimizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

    private void MaximizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

    private void CloseWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.Close();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you open any application let's say notepad , you will see a border around noptepad which lets you resize the window. When you maximize it , notice that the border is no more visible and you can't resize . This is the non-client area of application. By providing a custom windowchrome, you have taken full space including the non-client area and hence when you maximize your non-client area is outside the desktop visible area similar to notepad borders..Add a trigger on window for maximize property to put some margin .

Comment: Oh okay, I tried doing something like that but it doesn't work when I say drag my application to the top of the screen to maximize the window instead of pressing the maximize button?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at this youtube video. He addresses all the issues with resizing. Pretty in depth series overall.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDOxHx-AMqQ&t=1925s

Comment: Haha I actually ended up watching that, but I ended up finding a less complicated solution by myself! Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a sort of elegant solution to this problem. I simply assigned a name to the outermost grid, detected whenever it was maximized and added a margin to make sure the application was fully encompassing the screen and not going over. Then, when the screen size changed, I would remove said margin.

Here is some of my code:

Main functions:

```
private bool isMaximized = false;

        private void CheckMaximizeChange(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized || (isMaximized && WindowState != WindowState.Minimized)) ChangeWindow();
        }

        private void MaximizeWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.WindowState ^= WindowState.Maximized;

        private void ChangeWindow()
        {
            isMaximized = !isMaximized;
            MaximizeImageButton.Source = FindResource(MaximizeImageButton.Source == FindResource("window_maximize_icon") ? "window_restore_icon" : "window_maximize_icon") as DrawingImage;
            MainGrid.Margin = new Thickness(MainGrid.Margin == new Thickness(0) ? 7 : 0);
        }
```

then in the constructor of the application:

```
SizeChanged += CheckMaximizeChange;
```